# Json body could not be decoded: invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value

Tags: robotframework

I have successfully parsed the json file that I have, by entering the value into the global variable, where the global variable is needed in the json file. But when I try to hit request with that id I get response : {'errors': [{'message': "json body could not be decoded: invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value"}], 'data': None }

Please help what should I add and fix?

Here's my test case :

```
TC Edit Mission Detail For Input Target Task
[Documentation]             Example tc
[Tags]                      api test
Set Test ID                 9452

${payload}=         Get File    api-test/Main/collections/engagement/testing/intools/edit_mission.json
${payload}=         Evaluate    json.loads(${payload})    modules=json
Set To Dictionary   ${payload['variables']}   id    544
Log To Console      ${payload}

# Req body
${response}=                GraphQl Request     method=POST
...                         referrer_url=graphql/query
...                         payload_path=${payload}
...                         token=${token}
Set Global Variable         ${response}
Log To Console              ${response}

## Assertion
${expected_json}            Get File                    api-test/Main/assertions/expected-json/engagement/edit_mission.json
${expected_json}=           Convert To Json             ${expected_json}
```

My Keyword 'GraphQl Request'

```
@keyword("GraphQl Request")
def GraphQlRequest(method, referrer_url, payload_path=None, token=None, image=None):
url = "https://testingstaging.co/" + str(referrer_url) + ""
print(url)

if payload_path is not None:
    payload = payload_path
else:
    payload = {'operations': '{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { uploadImage(file: $file) { message } }", "variables": { "file": null } }',
               'map': '{ "0": ["variables.file"] }'}

if token is not None:
    token = token

if image is None:
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(token) + '',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
else:
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(token) + '',
        'Origin': 'https://testing123.co.id'
    }
    print(headers)


if image is None:
    response = requests.request("" + str(method) + "", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
    return response.json()

elif Path(image).suffix == '.csv':
    payload={'operations': '{"query":"mutation ($testingFile: Upload!) {\\n  createCampaign(input: {\\n    name:\\"Promo\\",\\n    startDate:\\"2020-01-02T00:00:00+07:00\\",\\n    endDate:\\"2020-06-06T00:00:00+07:00\\",\\n    type:\\"first_order\\",\\n    variables:\\"{\\\\\\"orderAmount\\\\\\": 2000, \\\\\\"orderOperation\\\\\\": \\\\\\"=\\\\\\"}\\",\\n    testing: $testing\\n  }) {\\n    message\\n  }}","variables":{"testing":null}}',
             'map': '{ "0": ["variables.testing"] }'}

    files=[
        ('0',(''+str(image)+'',open('api-test/Main/assets/'+str(image)+'','rb'),'text/csv'))
    ]

    response = requests.request("" + str(method) + "", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
    return response.json()
else:
    files=[
        ('0',(''+str(image)+'',open('api-test/Main/assets/'+str(image)+'','rb'),'image/jpg'))
    ]

    response = requests.request("" + str(method) + "", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
    return response.json()
```

Here's the response:

```
Edit Mission Detail For Input Target Task :: This test for input t... 
....{'query': 'mutation CreateMission($id: Int!, $details: 
String!) {\r\n  UpdateMissionDetail(input: { id: $id, details: 
$details })\r\n}\r\n', 'variables': {'details': '{"total_amount": 
518800}', 'id': '544'}}...{'errors': [{'message': "json body could not 
be decoded: invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of 
value"}],'data': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are being affected by the use of `"` in JSON content. You could try to escape them with `\\"`or replace by single quotes `'`.

Comment: can you give an example which part i should change?

Comment: It is hard to say where the error appears. It could be from the file edit_mission.json, or where the data is changes. You can see a mix of single quotes and escaped double codes, but in a part not reached by your current test (because no image path). Another thing I would take care is not to have Windows style line ends in the JASON data, because you get the \\r\\n values.